# Invalid URL, file still loaded

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, web

I'm posting this message because I'm facing a problem that I desperately can't solve!

The problem is that the url that I type in the address bar should not exist and yet my browser loads the file of my site (without the CSS and JS files), I note this:

I go to my index file of my site: `Acceuil.php`
Then I manually modify the url by typing `Hello` at the end to be able to generate a 404 error, which gives `Acceuil.php/Hello`.

Normally I would have to come across an error since `Acceuil.php` is a file and not a folder and well despite this, my file `Acceuil.php` is loaded (except CSS and Js files) and the address bar always stays `Acceuil.php/Hello`

What I don't understand is that `Acceuil.php/Hello` does not exist!
Have you ever had this or did I do something wrong? Can you help me please?

PS: I'm testing my .htaccess file and I'm using Wamp.

Comment: Try clearing the cache

Comment: Sorry for stating the obvious but if you're trying stuff at `.htaccess` then that must be the root of the problem. If unsure about that, then move the file elsewhere and try again.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late reply, but indeed it was the .htaccess file

Thanks for the advice!